In VS Code on windows when I run debugger for Bun I get URL cannot be parsed
When I run a Bun application with Elysia framework on Windows 11 in VS Code debugger, I get this error:

"ws+unix://C:\Users\amira\AppData\Local\Temp\pq0941kmg6.sock?wait=1" cannot be parsed as a URL.

Versions
Bun: 1.1.20
Elysia: 1.1.3
VS Code
Version: 1.91.1 (user setup)
Commit: f1e16e1e6214d7c44d078b1f0607b2388f29d729
Date: 2024-07-09T22:06:49.809Z
Electron: 29.4.0
ElectronBuildId: 9728852
Chromium: 122.0.6261.156
Node.js: 20.9.0
V8: 12.2.281.27-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22631
When I run the app in terminal using bun run app starts OK but when I run app in debugger I get the above error. I've also installed bun extension for VS Code.
